# I want get Phonegap(Cordova) device ready function

Tags: cordova

In Phonegap, I used that code to get device ready Function

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}

var onDeviceReady = function() {
    ~
};
```

But in cordova(Phonegap 3.0 over), this code results error.
How can I get Phonegap init Function?

Thank you.

Comment: Without the error we can't help you

Comment: Have you included cordova.js library in your html ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal way to use the deviceready event:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    your function here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Ready Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load //
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available //
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
</html>
```

From: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events